# How to get all the php code affecting a variable?

Tags: php, variables, getline

```
 <?php 
   class SomeClass {

   public function do_string(){
    $this->cacheFile(); 

    $unimportant_code = "unimportant";


    $someClass = new SomeClass(); 
    $some_string = $someClass->string; //Retruns 4 
    $some_string = $some_string + 2; 

    $variable = $some_string; //6 
    $this->pass($variable);
    }

   public function pass($var){ 
     //Do something with var and get the code I need
     $variable = $var; 

     require_once("template.php"); //In this file there's a code block 
     //{NOCACHE}
       //Do something with $variable;
     //{/NOCACHE} 


   }

   public function cacheFile(){ 
     //If file exists cache file 
     //If found {NOCACHE} {/NOCACHE} execute the code needed to change the $variable  between  {NOCACHE}{/NOCACHE} 
   }
}

    ?>
```

I want to get the exact coded affecting the value of $variable from the do_string() method that would be.

```
$someClass = new SomeClass() 
$some_string = $someClass->string //Retruns 4 
$some_string = $some_string + 2; 

$variable = $some_string; //6
```

So that later I can execute it if needed, I'm trying to make a cache system.
Is there anything like debug_backtrace() but for a $variable?

Comment: search for the $var string in your IDE?

Comment: You want both direct and non direct references?

Comment: @Martin even that isn't guaranteed, given variable scope and the possibility that $some_string might be used elsewhere in the code as a totally different variable, or that you can pass $some_string as a function argument where it's referenced by a completely different name

Comment: I want to get that code and do something with it in php,

Comment: Could you give us an illustration of what the intended output/outcome of your question is? I'm having difficulty establishing what it is you are trying to do exactly...

Comment: I have updated my code, basicaly I want to skip the execution of some code, but keep executing the code if the user calls a $variable and tells it not to cache that variable.

Comment: OK. So if I understand correctly you want the code between `$someClass = new SomeClass();` and `$someString` to be executed between `{NOCACHE}` and `{/NOCACHE}`?

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want, I want the  code between $someClass = new SomeClass(); and $someString to be executed in the methodname cacheFile() and then execute the code between {NOCACHE} and {/NOCACHE}. After that I'll just use return to skip the code that is cacheable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a further conversation with you about what you are trying to achieve, I am going to formally answer your question by saying that this cannot be done in the way you are hoping in any straightforward manner.